# ParametricNDSolve Value and Manipulate with 3 parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parametric-functions

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations, using `ParametricNDSolveValue`, where there are 3 parameters. The parameters are `Rast`, `\[Rho]` and one of the initial condition values, `a[0]`. I want to plot the result of this integration as a `Manipulate` plot, where each parameter can be independently varied.

My code is as follows:

```
Constants

au = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]]; 
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]]; 
Qpr = 1; 
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]]; 
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]]; 
Msun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]]; 
G = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], 
     ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/"Kilograms"^2]]; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
Myr = year*10^6; 
Gyr = year*10^9; 
Mwd = 0.6*Msun; 
Cst = 1.27; 
U = 1*10^17; 

Functions

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1); 
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]); 

Radiative Drag

RDdadtR\[Rho]a = -((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(c^2*(16*Pi*\[Rho]*Rast*a[t]*(1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2)))); 
RDdedtR\[Rho]a = -((15*L[t]*e[t])/(c^2*(32*Pi*Rast*\[Rho]*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2]))); 

RDsolR\[Rho]a = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][a][t] == RDdadtR\[Rho]a, 
     Derivative[1][e][t] == RDdedtR\[Rho]a, a[0] == a0, e[0] == 0.3}, {a[t], e[t]}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
    {Rast, \[Rho]}];
```

The parameters are `Rast`, `\[Rho]`, and the initial condition value, `a0`. I am unsure how to create a `Manipulate` plot with all three parameters.

PARAMETER DOMAINS: `Rast from 0.001 to 0.01`
`\[rho] from 1000 to 7000`
`a0 from 3*au to 20*au`
and the Plot domain: `t=0 to t=9 Gyr`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the desired ranges of the three parameters and of the plot?

Comment: @BobHanlon parameter domains: `Rast from 0.001 to 0.01`, `\[rho] from 1000 to 7000`, `a0 from 3*au to 20*au` and the Plot domain: `t=0 to t=9 Gyr`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Constants

```
au = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]];
c = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]];
Qpr = 1;
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]];
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]];
Msun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]];
G = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[
    Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/
     "Kilograms"^2]];
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]];
Myr = year*10^6;
Gyr = year*10^9;
Mwd = 6/10*Msun;
Cst = 1.27;
U = 10^17;
```

Functions

```
L[t_] := (326/100*Lsun*(Mwd/(6/10*Msun)))/
   (1/10 + t/Myr)^(118/100);
Roche[dens_] := (65/100*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(6/10*Msun))^(1/3))/
   (dens/3000)^3^(-1);
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]);
```

Radiative Drag

```
RDdadtRρa = -((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/
     (c^2*(16*Pi*ρ*Rast*a[t]*(1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2))));
RDdedtRρa = -((15*L[t]*e[t])/
     (c^2*(32*Pi*Rast*ρ*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2])));
```

Include `a0` as a parameter

```
RDsolRρa = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == RDdadtRρa, e'[t] == RDdedtRρa, 
    a[0] == a0, e[0] == 3/10}, {a, e}, 
   {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, {Rast, ρ, a0}];
```

**EDIT:** Plot of `a` rescaled to units of `au`

```
Manipulate[
 factor = If[func == 1, 1/au, 1];
 Plot[factor*RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[func]][t],
  {t, 0, 9 Gyr}],
 {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e"}},
 {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.001, 0.01, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ρ, 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 3, 20, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @BonHanlon Amazing! Is there a way of changing just the y axis scale just for `a`? I've changed the x -axis but find that the changes reflect for both the `a` and `e` plots.

Comment: @testing09 - probably; what change do you want?

Comment: I want the y axis of the `a` plot to be in units of `au` , instead of metres.